# Node.js Puppeteer setCookie not setting the cookie

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to set a certain cookie in the browser using Puppeteer, however when I run the code to set the cookie then console.log all the cookies on the page, it doesn't show up.

I'm running the following:

```
        const captchaCookie = {
            name: "hc_accessibility",
            value: "drR8A+cddQky0hclwHAG6gjwqk04IGvOhfYMP",
            domain: ".hcaptcha.com",
            path: "/",
            expires: new Date("2022-04-08T09:01:39.010Z").getTime(),
        };

        await page.setCookie(captchaCookie);
        
        await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

        console.log("Writing cookies to file.");
        const cookies = await page.cookies();
        await fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));
        console.log("Cookie file written.");
```

However, when I do this, in my `cookies.json` file this new cookie I set does not show up for some reason... I suspect this is why the accessibility cookie is not working in the browser for me. This is the JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "SCSessionId",
    "value": "jijt34hj2xijq4gul5i1fdjx",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1680902482.495723,
    "size": 35,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "isAdmin",
    "value": "False",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 12,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": ".ASPXAUTH",
    "value": "36268A1E1D2364038C3E1DA55B5D8235E41FAE61D1D8020E4066DB4B01711F9C330386672B7BF44D67388B0032C650E8BA348DB2E8F86E44A4ECFBF1520DB6F0217434729950DA8488724DAB924AC8074C6342355FB76F68C9938A29DFD0AB9CDDEDDF4529B3061816D45AE20578C53CB27FB533EE231BECE07C80BD8B84C777",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1649367682.495947,
    "size": 265,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "CookieSession",
    "value": "436212140.47873.0000",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 33,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": true,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "ak_bmsc",
    "value": "4AA3CEC4D9E6AE9969987921E3ED16D4~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQaKUQAoiJTwKAAQAAPxDnBQ/UlLIQjcFXA9N21BPy51wlF11AbL3wTqAl/x1xqAu2YMBnMxsfEC3vvlHphkagr+XDeaw6triB1ZTEhcauZXYfnTzjgCAJggjaAncgVFF/c8HKZRit5AKZey4Te9kwzf4uiSbCh+nWArwfa9qK7SG0K6EQ15cRWaPx474UU75/Tba2EEryU5+jk/WTBYsKgHCmk2lpt603TQX4+ySHL82ePh2y894prqsPaxMqmOx+NRsdF8COac1GZpBPYNrtBs9efPuWMkY37a1fCb23/SAHUZ1G6QFjgEBiOtHMJ1C/e5o3cxLeXTa3kv90O33HnuINDMLkomSt6VIkCKwi3+JbLeC/tm7Yxb8obHfOQLv58twashH5tvVOrG9gxYSoPeVyhI61HsEcnZuQAm0HfIoIkcpCGg99e04kp0nhhVvZi/5uLG3Rjpj2bzDkOhVUVWI244uiT6u3DFNcXatUkjU5gkM=",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1649373668.746263,
    "size": 571,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "bm_sv",
    "value": "235148FCE2F3956304D0C4670431EDA5~tnhmy/7Lr4mr9f7Xi0o1zWkbgCgatyrkx2dfx8Gz/fAF5zECmrnLYv3VS6IafZMOvoQyuDIu08DH93uSLJFYDvLNmap5md2HffL44BfYpPK+Ozd3BWkiWgHkiHWfgIqrB3h6g0PWd0MQ5m2ILerHuusjawfALt3gZjheilv631o=",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1649373668.992258,
    "size": 210,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "bm_sz",
    "value": "3A185B1E9853A46DEA0835A9A5F079CC~YAAQaKUQAoKJTwKAAQAADwjnBQ9NLqkc3gkbn/VA3Du7UCAd8q+4TkxdiIREjKDGp+JGCdXnNcdgBwUKfpqUM89zXWa1D1VrKxUwZWsOZmT4WKMpS4tqCIR+FygKJBVRuUOVoT9GaG4jhTykIIip7WUuzXMx8D4+Tasu4h/W8Nv/CFKZczch0VIgTrezor06Kf9IwSQZVQvGUsEA6xKryMp3qUcjS+rSn6skmsDgWBca5evadhdldwlf9q/3n7+7c4Ee8IJDbpyG3e2EMr/yzuc31boAChW52yK5ZL3Q3dJy8OsipxqNBVvF~3356486~4272438",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1649380868.647984,
    "size": 366,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "__RequestVerificationToken_L3N0b3Jl0",
    "value": "zS_1VWV9_bWnKOti2t7JemlrNrzVvmOB0hPJxHEyOcg2uWOhlQndSMbVyGrvWnz6_-o1j3oa9kKMC-Aqhb9KSdmGOZZZSZoCsOS7x8CQenc1",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 144,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "_WebStorePublishState",
    "value": "PRODUCTION",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 31,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "bm_mi",
    "value": "FB564BF7F20BF5685871930524714CF4~m2sVLAiMcIpi9+0BfDpJCBZ9EUgje/DT0VGyJNyrzwu7xK7fASsax/gW10hEK0ZfRWVwLtIeZgZMg+XLNcI6y9P/ZzyGYUR3taytO+KwuvnLw6x3277wU0yXLqgg59hc7qqCJcLUwNAnWnmJhqsoz3UbOxRCLTCiIymcQBTA2tnDeSHeZzWBTrKYoKF+rYhyuS+iukmM6NhwrLyIW9quQIVp+1O4HImjG/minoGBUnoCahXXU4JlPMua+8GL2KtjXIaFn/hXPfRPfWm+ID7BdQZp5Dn4tdR1loSosuZ4jYCw6h2rSFnWrWhAdGASuE8K",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1649373668.294547,
    "size": 358,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "culture",
    "value": "en",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 9,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "_abck",
    "value": "F37856EFEE58F3E50D8E7F3ED56968CC~-1~YAAQaKUQApKJTwKAAQAAG1bnBQdv7FpWhEr/RfbfIJSXfoLJJ4Vry+OWo2Olej8t8TPcjeLCeO2AspHip/dA/JxJQj1rud09kIyWHOA0tVTKpe+l8RHtJN8/0HGVRj9mNMrDcC8cmhtrMWLM+xuVoC2PTRFbzHLtW4qIdsxFzEPfCJ073JN/ImF2a0zijnsdb1kvP6q+wy9zIyemST5oQVMGA3Ov6qXqmGoDGinnKRTSx9s9W9b2U2Ba8DOBNz7Hu+IZFw8xh+Tn5SCiRDKPAjPgk5lnG45Rr9oE4ZpnIFwDBUBU+Fkt76cWajtPkKUmlOX7Q+ZeEQSPOCjJeOT0dCaTtK83YET0ECJiz7sDzVBnJNqYUmIGdNZ6pAqI0b9NFri3epB74Y7EHgTDdVy2EGM=~-1~-1~-1",
    "domain": ".scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": 1680902488.628089,
    "size": 458,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": true,
    "session": false,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "_WebStoreculture",
    "value": "1",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 17,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "persona",
    "value": "other",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 12,
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  },
  {
    "name": "ASP.NET_SessionId",
    "value": "jijt34hj2xijq4gul5i1fdjx",
    "domain": "www.scottycameron.com",
    "path": "/",
    "expires": -1,
    "size": 41,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "secure": false,
    "session": true,
    "sameSite": "Lax",
    "sameParty": false,
    "sourceScheme": "Secure",
    "sourcePort": 443
  }
]
```

Would anyone know the reason why this cookie isn't appearing when I try to get the page's cookies?

Answer (score -1):

It's because [`page.cookies()`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.cookies) method without specified URL returns cookies only for the current page URL (which seems to be: [www.scottycameron.com](http://www.scottycameron.com)) and what you've set is considered a 3rd party cookie in that sense (.hcaptcha.com).

```js
const cookiesA = await page.cookies('.scottycameron.com') // equals to "await page.cookies()"
const cookiesB = await page.cookies('.hcaptcha.com')
```

See in Docs:

> If no URLs are specified, this method returns cookies for the current page URL. If URLs are specified, only cookies for those URLs are returned.

If you want to check cookies for both at the same time (including 3rd party), you can use:

```js
const cookies = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies')
```